# Output Externall JSON Api on Page Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, view, controller

I want to display  a statement on a view page, and present all data from the JSON API. The JSON code has a link to it. I have so far only managed to use:

```
require 'json/pure'
require 'open-uri'

def index
   content = open("MY_JSON_URL").read
   render text:  content
 end
```

But this only outputs the JSON formatted data. I want to be able to edit and present this data in a good readable form(add styling and stuff to it). Preferably in html. How can I do this. I want to be able to edit it so that it will make it look readable but I just want to view it on a page and do nothing else. Is this still REST?. As part of my task I've also been asked to serve it up on a web server, what does that mean? I'm sorry for my weak knowledge but i'm trying my hardest to understand I just need to be pointed into the right direction and I can nail this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering text content you should return hash from controller. To do this. You can use `JSON.parse`.

```
def index
   content = open("MY_JSON_URL").read
   @hash = JSON.parse content
end
```

Now you can iterate data on view easily.

Comment: so would that mean like do a loop in index.html.erb ?